# Trying to pass number of results variable in php

Tags: php, mysqli, return, visibility

I am passing an  sql query through a function that returns the number of results from a SELECT query. The result is a correct count for the mysqli_num_rows() method but does not set the counter variable equal to that number and instead keeps the counter equal to its original value.

```
public function getNum($sql){
    $count = 0;  //set the count variable
    if($result = $this->query($sql)){
        //echo 'No results for criteria';
    $count = mysqli_num_rows($result); //count is properly set to number
    }                                  //does not modify outside count variable
   return $count;  //returning 0 or whatever count was originaly set to
}   //count does not change despite $count inside the if statement being changed
```

Here's what the $this->query is

```
public function __construct(){
    $this->mysqli = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', '', 'mydb');
}

public function query($sql){
    return $this->mysqli->query($sql);
}
```

I know for sure the  query is executing. The problem is that the variable is not being changed for the return.

Comment: Are you 100% sure that the query is executed? `$this->query` can you share the code for that method? And the query you pass to this method?

Comment: Show more code please

Comment: I know that the sql is all working, it has echoed the correct number of results if I place echo $count within the if statement. But outside, the $count variable is not changed.

Comment: I've never seen object-style and procedural style database actions mixed like that. Are you sure $count actually has a value before leaving the if(){} block? Can you produce complete code and output?

Comment: @Gralgrathor You can mix object-oriented and procedural `mysqli_`. It works, because the procedural ones basically calls the object ones. You should stick with one or the other, though - doing the same across the code, but *it works*.

Comment: @PjRigor Can you show how you use this code? You're not calling `getNum()` on a `query()` method?

Answer (score -1):

As I understand you issue, you want to set variable `$count` inside a function but you should know that variables inside functions can't be accessed outside and vise-versa this is because of [variable scope in PHP](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.scope.php).

You can try this:

```
var $count;
function set_count($new_value) { 
  $this->count = $new_value; 
} 
function get_count() { 
  return $this->count; 
}
public function getNum($sql){
    $count = 0;  //set the count variable
    if($result = $this->query($sql)){
      $count = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    }
   //set `$count`
   $this->set_count($new_value);             
   return $count;
}
//and if you want to get the count
echo $this->get_count();
```

Comment: It isn't a variable-scope issue, because the variable is defined inside the `getNum()` method, and returned inside it.

Comment: variables defined inside function can't be accessed outside, and return dose not return the `$var` the variable it returns the value of the variable only.

Comment: They can be returned from the function, to be used in the global scope after it's called. It returns the value, indeed, but that's all you need.

Comment: This is why we need more complete code. For all we know, OP is trying to do the following:

$count = 0;
$x = getNum(bla);
assert( $count != 0 ); // aargh!

Comment: What we need to see is how OP is *using* the code above ;-) Because isolated and properly used, it works - I've tried it. For all we know, OP's trying to use `$result = $something->query($sql); echo $result->getNum($sql);` in the global scope, which *won't work*, because he's then calling the `query()` method twice. I doubt it's a scope issue, more like how the methods are being called - but as you said yourself, "*This is why we need more complete code*" - and in turn, makes the question so much harder to answer (and one should wait until we know all the facts) :-)

Comment: Thank you all for providing your input. It looks as if the error was caused by not including single quotes around the variable I was passing through tot he query... Embarrassing but thank you for validating my object oriented method of approach.